# What does Russian "Meddling" mean?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, russian-federation

Almost daily we hear that Russia meddled in the 2016 presidential election.  What does it mean to meddle?  What is the evidence?

> **med·dle**
>
> *verb*
>
> interfere in or busy oneself unduly with something that is not one's
>   concern.

- [Trump says Russia most likely meddled in the 2016 election but
  'nobody really knows for sure'](http://www.businessinsider.com/trump-believes-russia-meddled-2016-election-2017-7)
- [Clapper: No evidence others besides Russia meddled in election](http://www.cnn.com/2017/07/06/politics/james-clapper-donald-trump-russia/index.html)
- [Evidence is mounting that Russia took 4 clear paths to meddle in the
  US election](http://www.businessinsider.com/evidence-russia-meddled-in-us-election-2017-6)

Even that last link whose title I believe is click bait, really doesn't describe WHAT Russia did.  It does describe that there was hacking done from a Russian source or attempted hacking - but it doesn't say that they did anything bad besides maybe logged in.  It even describes how the polls were attempted to be altered, but apparently, they were not.

What is this meddling we hear about and is it actually bad as we're lead to believe?

Comment: Also related: [What is the rationale for foreign interference in a democratic election being intrinsically bad?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18504/what-is-the-rationale-for-foreign-interference-in-a-democratic-election-being-in/18514#18514)

Comment: I think it is duplicate. The additional parts to this question are "what does the word meddle mean" and "Is meddling bad". The first is off topic, the second is opinion based.